# UIViewController as a singleton

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, singleton

I have a UIViewController in a tab bar application. I've added the controller from the MainWindow.nib file (i.e. not programatically).

My question is how can I make my view controller a singleton? (To resolve the Facebook delegate issue).

Comment: This is a really bad idea. It's this kind of abuse of singletons that makes many more experienced programmer advise avoiding them all together.

Comment: No, but implementing a view-controller as a singleton smells fishy indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to make your "Facebook connection code" a singleton (or part of the app delegate), but not the view controller itself. Then just wire up the FB thing with any view controller that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to create singletons (but I don't think you do, please rethink your design - what is "the facebook delegate problem" exactly?), look here [in Apple's sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32)

Comment: Hi, I really don't want to do that but after reading some posts like:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215797/fbdidlogin-never-called-facebook-ios-sdk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244609/fbdidlogin-not-called I got the impression that that's the only solution.

Comment: I just did an FB controller myself last week. No singletons were hurt during the production of this view controller ;-)

Comment: To clarify, if there is indeed a problem with multiple clients using the FB library (I have no clue, just guessing from your remarks) then you still shouldn't have a problem, the view controllers are not created from thin air.

Comment: @OK, so how did you go about getting the delegate to work? In my app delegate, I have added someView=[[SomeView alloc]init] and then then I have implemented the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
 as suggested. However not a sound from the fbDidLogin method in my SomeView controller.

Comment: I used the stock code from the FB SDK and it worked. Have you tried using the "inline web view" authorization style? My app works with both styles, BTW. You say you use nibs, but at the same time also use programmatic instantiation (`someView=[[SomeView alloc]init]`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can make any class a singleton adding something like this to the .m file (and you also have to add declaration to the .h):

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
  static id sharedInstance;
  @synchronized(self) {
    if (!sharedInstance)
      sharedInstance = [[ClassName alloc] init];
    return sharedInstance;
  }
}
```