# getInstance before initWithNibName:

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a class named `IGMapViewController`

In that I have

```
static IGMapViewController *instance =nil;

+(IGMapViewController *)getInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance==nil) {
            instance= [IGMapViewController new];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // more code
        instance = self;
    }

    return self;
}
```

If use the object in more then 1 class but only use `initWithNibName` in one class.

In a class named `IGRouteController` in the init method i use `_mapViewController = [IGMapViewController getInstance];` this happens before the `initWithNibName` gets executed in another class.

In `IGRouteController` I have a method `updateRouteList` in that method I use:

`[_mapViewController drawSuggestedRoute:suggestedRoute];`

It all does run but I can't see the result.

If i use:

```
IGMapViewController *wtf = [IGMapViewController getInstance];
[wtf drawSuggestedRoute:suggestedRoute];
```

Then it does work great.

So is it possible to get a instance and init later with a nib?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: get a instance somewhere. The initWithNib and make where i got the instance be the same as the one that was created with initWithNib.

Comment: I've worked with apps that tried to have view controller singletons like this, it was unpleasant, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I see what you are trying to accomplish.  You want to initialize a singleton instance of your class from a nib.  Correct?

When you initialize your instance, you are using `[IGMapViewController new]` which is presumably not the intended behavior.  How about this (untested...)?

```
+ (id)sharedController
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static IGMapViewController *cSharedInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        cSharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
    });
    return cSharedInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clankill3r,

You should avoid creating singleton `UIViewController`s (see comments in this discussion [UIViewController as a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781749/uiviewcontroller-as-a-singleton)). This has been also highlighted by **@CarlVeazey**.

IMHO, you should create a `UIViewController` each time you need it. In this case your view controller would be a reusable component. When you create a **new** instance of your controller, just inject (though a property or in the initializer the data you are interested in, `suggestedRoute` in this case).

A simple example could be the following:

```
// YourViewController.h
- (id)initWithSuggestedRoute:(id)theSuggestedRoute;

// YourViewController.m
- (id)initWithSuggestedRoute:(id)theSuggestedRoute
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // set the internal suggested route, e.g.
        _suggestedRoute = theSuggestedRoute; // without ARC enabled _suggestedRoute = [theSuggestedRoute retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self drawSuggestedRoute:[self suggestedRoute]];
}
```

For further info about `UIViewController`s, I really advice to read two interesting post by **@Ole Begemann**.

- [Passing Data Between View Controllers](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/)
- [initWithNibName:bundle: Breaks Encapsulation](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/01/initWithNibName-bundle-breaks-encapsulation/)

Hope that helps.